# How to get the player variable from MediaSessionService example in docs?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediasession, android-media3

Maybe it's just me but `Media3 Create a MediaController` section in android docs is just missing the last part for me which is getting the "player" and using it in a composable.

I want the session for the notification as well and the player will play a url not local media.

I have `PlaybackService.kt` which is exactly what's in the documents

```kotlin
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.media3.common.MediaMetadata
import androidx.media3.common.PlaybackException
import androidx.media3.common.Player
import androidx.media3.session.MediaController
import androidx.media3.session.MediaSession
import androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService
import androidx.media3.session.SessionToken
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors

class PlaybackService : MediaSessionService() {
    private lateinit var controllerFuture: ListenableFuture<MediaController>
    lateinit var player: MediaController
    private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val sessionToken = SessionToken(this, ComponentName(this, PlaybackService::class.java))
        controllerFuture =
            MediaController.Builder(this, sessionToken).buildAsync()
        controllerFuture.addListener({
            player = controllerFuture.get()
            initController()

        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
    }


    private fun initController() {
        player.addListener(object : Player.Listener {

            override fun onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata: MediaMetadata) {
                super.onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata)
            }

            override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                super.onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)
            }

            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
            }

            override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
                super.onPlayerError(error)
            }

            override fun onPlayerErrorChanged(error: PlaybackException?) {
                super.onPlayerErrorChanged(error)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession? =
        mediaSession


    // The user dismissed the app from the recent tasks
    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        if (!player.playWhenReady || (player.mediaItemCount == 0)) {
            // Stop the service if not playing, continue playing in the background
            // otherwise.
            stopSelf()
        }
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        player.stop()
        player.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

and in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
...
...
<service
   android:name=".PlaybackService"
   android:exported="true"
   android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService" />
      <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

now, I just need that player variable in a composable.

Maybe something like sending it to `HomeScreen(player: MediaController)`

I've tried multiple examples from open source projects but all of them are using MVVM with big projects which over overcomplicated.

I'm still learning, I just need to use something like `player.play(url: String)` and `player.stop()` on a button click and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself in this same situation about a year ago so I came up with a helper function to deal with it. You can call this with a context. Don't forget to replace the media service class with yours.

```
@Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
private suspend inline fun <reified T : Service> getMediaControllerForService(context: Context): MediaController =
    suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        val mediaControllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(
            context,
            SessionToken(context, ComponentName(context, T::class.java))
        ).buildAsync()

        mediaControllerFuture.addListener({
            val controller = mediaControllerFuture.get()
            continuation.resumeWith(Result.success(controller))
        }, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    }

 // You can use it as

 mediaController = getMediaControllerForService<MediaService>(context = context)
```

It is also worth stating that you should accept the incoming connection from your MediaService class by attaching a callback to your `MediaSession` object and implementing the `onConnect` method

```
    val mediaSession = MediaSession
        .Builder(this, player)
        .setCallback(object : MediaSession.Callback {
                override fun onConnect(
                    session: MediaSession,
                    controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo
                ): MediaSession.ConnectionResult {
                    return MediaSession.ConnectionResult.accept(
                        SessionCommands
                            .Builder()
                            .build(),
                        playerCommands
                    )
                }
            }
        ).build()
```

Comment: getting an error: ```java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: Session rejected the connection request.```

Comment: You need to add a callback in your service class to accept the connection. I have updated the answer

Comment: I just needed to add onAddMediaItems callback as well and it works great. Thank you so much!